# How do I choose the correct list depending on an argument value?

Tags: python

I have a class which contains several lists, i.e.:

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self, list_A, list_B, ..., list_Z):
        self.list_A = list_A
        (...)
        self.list_Z = list_Z
```

then I need a method which will append an element to one of the lists. What I did now is something like *switch case* from C:

```
def add_to_list(self, list_name, item):
    if list_name == 'A':
        self.list_A.append(item)
    elif list_name == 'B':
        self.list_B.append(item)
    (...) and so on
```

Its very uneffective, and needs a lot of work if I want to change something. 
Is there a way to make it shorter? I imagine something analogous to *string.format()*:

```
self.list_{}.append(item) .format(list_name)
```

Comment: how about a dict of list with an appropriate key

Comment: Why do you have 26 `list_A`, `list_B`, etc. attributes, rather than a list of 26 lists?

Comment: @user2357112 I need to distinct them by name, like citizens_Chicago, citizens_NY, citizens_Washington etc. Indexing with numbers would be messy.

Comment: @RedFidd Couldn't you then just use a dictionary where you reference them by key names?

Comment: @therealprashant you mean lists_dict = { 'list_A' : [], 'list_B' : [], ..., 'list_Z' : []} ? That would make sense :-) I'll need to check, if this would work with the other methods I use though.

Comment: Yes I am saying that only...

Comment: Instead of checking the `list_name`, can't you just pass the list you want to add the item to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't build your programs logic around your variable names. Please specify the criteria one item has to fullfill in order to be sorted to a particular list.
If its simple alphabetical order, just express it within your code.

Example:

```
class my_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_A = []
        self.list_B = []
        self.dict = { "A":self.list_A, "B":self.list_B }

    def add_to_list(self, key):
        # Logic in here
        self.dict.get(key[:1]).append(key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = my_class()
    c.add_to_list("Apple")
    c.add_to_list("Bus")
    c.add_to_list("Airplane")
    print(c.dict["A"])
    print(c.dict["B"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `getattr` to access the attribute

```
def append(self, list_name, item):
    getattr(self, 'list_%s' % list_name).append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this with the help of a dictionary.

```
class base:
    def __init__(self, * pack):
        self.dictitems={}
        for i, j in zip('abcdefg',pack):
            self.dictitems[i]=j


    def add(self,list_name,item,key):

        self.dictitems[key].append(item)

    def printdict(self):
        print(self.dictitems)

a,b,c =[ [] for i in range(3)]
z=base(a,b,c)
z.add(b, 5 ,key ='b')
z.add(b, 7 ,key ='b')
z.add(c, 7 ,key ='c')
z.printdict()
```